# Parallelogram Law of Force Addition

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

In most of the mechanics textbooks , the [Parallelogram Law of Force Addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_of_force) is stated without any justification or an experiment to confirm this law. Also after introducing this law forces are also decomposed without any justification.
Please suggest any links or books related to this.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related Math SE post: [Proof for parallelogram law of vector addition](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1407042/proof-for-parallelogram-law-of-vector-addition).

Comment: Try [Routh's book, 1891](https://books.google.de/books?id=iRY9AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=newton%27s+proof+of+parallelogram+law&source=bl&ots=jVRdzKwTTy&sig=Exkn5mi-atX9-Q0sU4blIoly5TA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj097Tm_LTNAhWlDMAKHRGvCjEQ6AEIQTAH#v=onepage&q=newton's%20proof%20of%20parallelogram%20law&f=false).  He devotes several pages to Newton's proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The justification for Parallelogram Law of Force Addition is that second Newton's Law is a vector equation linear in force.

Let us suppose we have a particle which can possibly acted by two forces $\vec F_1$ and $\vec F_2$. Newtonian Mechanics assumes that if $\vec r_1(t)$ and $\vec r_2(t)$ are the position of the particle when only $\vec F_1$ and $\vec F_2$, respectively are non vanishing, then the position when both forces are acting together is just $\vec r(t)=\vec r_1(t)+\vec r_2(t)$. This is known as the Superposition Principle and as we can see it just means we can sum the vectors $\vec F_1+\vec F_2\equiv \vec F$ and plug this into the equation of motion, 
$$\frac{d^2\vec r}{dt^2}=\vec F.$$

Comment: How do we justify the Superposition Principle.

Comment: @user348631 This is an empirical fact. Whenever a theory satisfy the Superposition Principle we are expected to formulate a law based on a linear differential equation (such as the second Newton's Law). Any linear differential equation obeys the Superposition Principle.

Comment: Are their any easy demonstrations?

Comment: Any particle acted by two forces can be used to verify the SP. A  However this does not prove the SP is always true, as in fact it is not. In General Relativity for instance it is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the justification is that the experiments confirm it! You apply two different forces at the same time and the effect is just as if you had applied a single force which would be the parallelogram addition of the original two forces. Formally, it is sometimes heard that the reason parallelogram law works is because the forces are vectors. But the physical essence of the things going on lies in realizing that it is a fact derived from experiments that the entities we call force add the way described via parallelogram law and we call them vectors.

Comment: I know that it's experimentally confirmed but I want to know exactly which experiments are used to confirm it with an high degree of accuracy.